# find out the resultant links of google search inside an android app

Tags: java, android, windows

I need to find the resultant links for some specific google search inside my android application. Please anyone help me to find out a way to do this. i need only the links searching by googlle. if anyone post some sample code, it wiil be very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

i cant think of a reason why you would need only the links.. simply open the search page in webview.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a PHP curl program to capture the resultant web page and then use some regular expressions to grab the links out of the result page.